# LaTeX: Align first table line with \item contents

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, vertical-alignment

Consider this example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Blablabla bla bla bla.
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
            Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
            Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.\\
        \end{tabular}
    \item Next question
\end{enumerate}
```

LaTeX will vertically center the table, which looks pretty weird. It basically looks like this:

```
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
1. Blablabla bla bla bla. Consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.
```

How can I manage for the consecutive lignes to line up under the first one (with the same margin)? Something which would look like this:

```
1. Blablabla bla bla bla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                          Consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `tabular` environment has an optional argument to specify the vertical alignment. The default is centered, the other options are `t` and `b` for top and bottom.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Blablabla bla bla bla.
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
            Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
            Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.\\
        \end{tabular}
    \item Next question
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: And how about the same but with a `\hline` at the top of the table?

Comment: @Albert: Use `\firsthline` (of the package `array`).

Answer (score 0):

Following Juan A. Navarro answer we can have also results like this one:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Blablabla bla bla bla.\\
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
            Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
            Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.\\
        \end{tabular}
        \item Next question with blabla bla.\\
        \begin{tabular}[t]{llr}
            I. &Consectetur adipiscing elit.&125.12\\
            II. &Consectetur adipiscing elit.&3.25\\
            III. &Consectetur  elit.&0.35\\
            IV. &Consectetur adipiscing.&2783.25\\
        \end{tabular}
    \item Next question.\\
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
        Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
        Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.\\
    \end{tabular}
    \item Next question with bla.\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
    Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
    Donec eu ante non mi sagittis molestie.\\
    Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
\end{tabular}
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```