# Split-like environment inside cases environment

Tags: amsmath, horizontal-alignment, cases, multline, environments

I'd like to have a `cases` environment with some cases that are too long to fit on one line. I tried this:

```
\begin{cases}
  \begin{split}
    long expression \\ second line of long expression
  \end{split} & condition \\
  ...
```

but I get the warning

> Package amsmath Warning: Cannot use 'split' here;
>   trying to recover with 'aligned' on input line 201.

It automatically replaces the `split` with an `aligned` environment, which looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to get these long expressions to behave like they were in `split` or `multline` environments, with the top line flush left and the next line indented a little?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer to define a short(er) notation such that the separate cases would fit on a single line?

Comment: @Taco Hoekwater, Yes.

Comment: The solutions below work fine, but they change the size of the math.  It seems that `cases` changes to `textstyle`, but `aligned` changes back to `displaystyle` (so you get bigger fractions and sums, etc.).  As explained in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274456/5741), you can get back to `textstyle` by defining a new environment `talign` that redefines `displaystyle` as `textstyle`.  (You could also do that manually in a group, if you prefer.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I'd follow amsmath's suggestion to use aligned instead of split:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \text{left hand side} =
  \begin{cases}
    \!\begin{aligned}%[b]
       & \text{a very long expression} \\
       & + \text{that continues on the next line}
    \end{aligned}           & \text{1st condition} \\%[1ex]
    \text{short expression} & \text{2nd condition}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Does this yield the output you want? (Note that the `\!` in front of `aligned` is needed since that environment adds a `\,` we have to cancel out.)

EDIT: If you want to achieve alignment and spacing as Niel suggests (@Niel: I would want that; good catch), then just remove the two `%` in the code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `aligned` could take arguments for  vertical alignment with things around it! Semantically speaking, that makes your answer better.

Comment: @Niel: I didn't know that either, I just put it there and it worked :-)

Comment: Thanks, it was the `&`'s at the beginning of each line that did what I wanted! To get `multline`-like indenting, I put `\quad` in between the second `&` and the `+`.

Comment: @Niel: It seems that I [did already know that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/aligning-a-multiline-formula-with-the-bullet-of-itemize/4424#4424) and forgot it again ...

Comment: The spacing/alignment at the beginning of the line is wrong though (compared to Niel's answer). The `a` is preceded by a bigger space than the `s` of `short` on the third line.

Comment: @neo: Good catch, thanks a lot!! That's the dreaded `aligned` / [`gathered`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78500) / [`multlined`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66517) problem. These environments add a `\,` (whyever). See my edit.

Comment: Ah thanks, that's better. Although there still is a difference in alignment (that's probably just how `aligned` works), see my comment at Niel's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative construction to Hendrik's, which aligns the `1st condition` with the bottom-most line of the long expression (which I would suggest as good practise generally for readability). I also add vertical space between the two formulae to make it easier to separate the two visually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \text{left hand side} =
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
       & \text{a very long expression} \\
       & + \text{that continues on the next line} && \text{1st condition}
    \\[1ex]
       & \text{short expression}                  && \text{2nd condition}
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

I omit the `cases` environment here, as all of the alignment work that it does is now better performed by `aligned`. The alignment tabs are chosen to get uniform alignment of the conditions, and left-alignment for everything involved; they can be changed to obtain right-alignment where desired.

Comment: Using `aligned` still results in inconsistent alignment at the beginning of each line. The beginning is not fully left-aligned unlike with the cases env. See my example: http://pastie.org/5376249

Comment: @neo: do you mean just that there is a little extra space in between the brace and the formulae? I've often deliberately added space in `cases` environments in order to obtain a comparable amount of space.

Comment: No, have a close look at the "r" in my example, it's a bit too far right compared to "z". Using only `cases`, the left corner of both letters align correctly.

Comment: @neo: I see, it would seem to be precisely because `\operatorname{r}` is gives `r` the spacing appropriate to operators (which the tab-stops of the align environments try to accomodate specially). If we use `{\operatorname{r}}` (which is ugly), the problem goes away.

Comment: Oh boy... how do you know all that?? :D Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

## ShareLatex

Just to give concrete example rather than only putting text assume that you have written the following cases equation

```
\begin{equation*}
L_{t}= 
\begin{cases}
    A_{t} & \text{if }A_{t}\leq L_{t-1}e^{g} \\ 
    L_{t-1}e^{g} & \text{if }L_{t-1}e^{g}<A_{t}\leq
    L_{t-1}e^{g}+E_{t-1}e^{g}+B_{t-1} \\ 
    \begin{split}
    L_{t-1}e^{g} \\
    +\alpha \delta(1-b)(A_{t}-L_{t-1}e^{g}-E_{t-1}e^{g}-B_{t-1})  
    \end{split} & \text{if } A_{t}>L_{t-1}e^{g}+E_{t-1}e^{g}+B_{t-1}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

As you may see it is not fitted well then you may write the following

```
\begin{equation*}
  L_{t}= 
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
        & A_{t} && \text{if }A_{t}\leq L_{t-1}e^{g} \\
        & L_{t-1}e^{g} && \text{if }L_{t-1}e^{g}<A_{t}\leq L_{t-1}e^{g}+E_{t-1}e^{g}+B_{t-1} \\
        & L_{t-1}e^{g} \\
       & \quad + \alpha \delta(1-b)(A_{t}-L_{t-1}e^{g}-E_{t-1}e^{g}-B_{t-1})   && \text{if } A_{t}>L_{t-1}e^{g}+E_{t-1}e^{g}+B_{t-1} \\
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
```

Which will be printed as
[image]