# Newline in a "cases" environment

Tags: lyx, line-breaking, cases

I have the same issue as in this question: [Split-like environment inside cases environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/split-like-environment-inside-cases-environment) with one difference - I would like to get the same result with LyX, using as little LaTeX code as possible. How can I do that?

Here's my formula:

```
\begin{cases}
\epsilon & \exists k\left[i_{k}=0\right]\\
\mbox{LCS}\left(X_{1}\left(i_{1}-1\right),X_{2}\left(i_{2}- 1\right),\ldots,X_{n}\left(i_{n}-1\right)\right)||\sigma_{1}^{i_{1}} & \sigma_{1}^{i_{1}}=\sigma_{2}^{i_{2}}=\ldots=\sigma_{n}^{i_{n}}\\
\max\left\{ \mbox{LCS}\left(X_{1}\left(i_{1}-1\right),X_{2}\left(i_{2}\right),\ldots,X_{n}\left(i_{n}\right)\right),\mbox{LCS}\left(X_{1}\left(i_{1}\right),X_{2}\left(i_{2}-1\right),\ldots,X_{n}\left(i_{n}\right)\right),\ldots,\mbox{LCS}\left(X_{1}\left(i_{1}\right),X_{2}\left(i_{2}\right),\ldots,X_{n}\left(i_{n}-1\right)\right)\right\}  & \mbox{else}\end{cases}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
\epsilon & \exists k\left[i_{k}=0\right]\\
\text{LCS}\left(X_{1}\left(i_{1}-1\right),X_{2}\left(i_{2}- 1\right),\ldots,X_{n}
        \left(i_{n}-1\right)\right)||\sigma_{1}^{i_{1}} \qquad
              & \sigma_{1}^{i_{1}}=\sigma_{2}^{i_{2}}=\ldots=\sigma_{n}^{i_{n}}\\
  \begin{aligned}[t]\arraycolsep=0pt
     \max\{ &
      \text{LCS}\big(X_{1}(i_1-1),X_2(i_{2}),\ldots,X_{n}(i_n)\big),\\ &
       \text{LCS}\left(X_1(i_1),X_{2}(i_2-1),\ldots,X_n(i_n)\right),\\ &
     \ldots, \\ & 
       \text{LCS}
       \left(X_{1}\left(i_{1}\right),X_{2}\left(i_{2}\right),\ldots,X_{n}
       \left(i_{n}-1\right)\right)\}
  \end{aligned}  & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

pages 18f and 56 of the [Mathmode](http://mirrot.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) document show you the cases environemnt with linebreaks. More informations are only possible when you give an example of what you did.