# Removing a line break following \item before \begin{align*}

Tags: lists, align

I'm trying to remove the line break that occurs when trying to start an equation within a list. This is what I'm trying to do, and the output that occurs:

```
...
\item \begin{align*}
P(J|B,I,M)&=P(B)*P(M)*P(I|B,M)*P(G|B,I,M)*P(J|G)\\
&=.9*.1*.9*.9*.9\\
&=\boxed{.06561}
\end{align*}
...
```

I want to get rid of the extraneous line break that occurs at the beginning of the list item:
[image]

Comment: try `\item$\begin{aligned}[t]...\end{aligned}$`, see how it goes...

Comment: another possible duplicate: [aligning a multiline formula with the bullet of itemize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4423/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special thanks to @cmhughes.

The solution is to use math mode with the aligned command:

```
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
...
\end{aligned}$
```